# every continuous map $S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ can be extended to continuous map $B^2 \rightarrow B^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $S^1$ denote the unit circle, and $B^2$ denote the closed unit disk. I came across this question and got stuck:

Q:) Every continuous map $f :S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ can be extended to continuous map $B^2 \rightarrow B^2$. If $f$ is a homeomorphism, then we can choose the extension to be a homeomorphism also.

I tried the obvious approach, namely for $x\in B^2-{0},$ define the extension by $x\rightarrow ||x||.f(x/||x||)$, but this does not seem to work,or I cannot figure out why this might work. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This does work, of course if you additionally say that this is for $x\ne0$ and send $0\mapsto0$. Specifically, what are your difficulties?

Comment: If I remember correctly, a continue function $f \colon S^1 \to X$ ($X$ topological space) is nullhoomotopic if and only if $f$ can be extended to a continuous function from the disk to $X$

Comment: @Riccardo here the codomains are different too. With nullhomotopic the codomains are the same.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma oh you are right! thanks for pointing out!

Comment: But Riccardo your point is still useful. Every continuous map $S^1\to S^1$ can be extended to a map $S^1\to B^2$ by composing with inclusion of the boundary, and then because $B^2$ is contractible, the map must be nullhomotopic, therefore the map can be extended to a map $B^2\to B^2$.

Comment: @Vladimir : I cannot show that the map is continuous by ϵ−δ argument. It seems that two nearby points inside the disk may get mapped to distant points by my map. Can you explain why you think it works?

Comment: The map is obviously continuous on $B\setminus 0$, where it is a composition of continuous mappings. So we need to prove only the continuity at $0$, which is obvious as well, because $||(||x||f(x/||x||)||=||x||$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map 
$$
x\mapsto\begin{cases}||x||f(x/||x||), &x\ne0\\0,&x=0\end{cases}
$$
is obviously continuous on $B\setminus0$, where it is a composition of the continuous mappings $x\mapsto x/||x||$, $f$, and multiplication by $||x||$. So we need to prove only the continuity at 0, which is obvious as well, because $||(||x||f(x/||x||)||=||x||$.

Comment: It might be obvious and I might be dumb, but can you still point out which continuous maps you are composing for the map from $B^2 - 0$? that is where I am facing difficulty.

Comment: I have edited my answer; see there. $x\mapsto x/||x||$ is continuous outside $x=0$, because $x\mapsto||x||$ is continuous and $||x||\ne0$.

Comment: you are suggesting the composition $B^2 -0 \rightarrow S^1\rightarrow S^1\rightarrow B^2$, but I do not understand the last map $S^1\rightarrow B^2$. Can you explicitly state the map?

Comment: No, not that. $B^2\setminus 0\to S^1\times (0,1]\to S^1\times (0,1]\to B^2$; the first map is $x\mapsto(x/||x||,||x||)$, the second $(y,r)\mapsto (f(y),r)$, and the third $(z,r)\mapsto zr$.

Comment: I think one can show too  that if $f$ is a homeomorphism, so is this new map. One only needs to show that it is bijective if $f$ is.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yeah the extension is clearly a bijection if $f$ is a bijection by just looking at polar coordinates. Then you just apply the theorem "A continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism".

Answer (score 3):

Riccardo's comment is still useful you just need to be clever in how you apply it. Every continuous map $f\colon S^1\to S^1$ can be extended to a map $\tilde{f}\colon S^1\to B^2$ by composing with inclusion $i\colon S^1\to B^2$ of the boundary, so
$$\tilde{f}=f\circ i$$
and then because $B^2$ is contractible, $\tilde{f}$ must be nullhomotopic, therefore the map can be extended to a map $B^2\to B^2$ because of the theorem which says that any map from the circle to a space is nullhomotopic if and only if that map can be extended to the disc.

For the second part, just note that the identity on the circle can be extended to a homemorphism of the disc (also the identity) and so, using the fact that a homeomorphism of the circle is homotopic to the identity on the circle (or reflection), you can easily form you map in pieces (do the outer annulus first via the relevant homotopy and then 'fill in the hole' with a disc which corresponds to the identity.)

Comment: can you give a reference for the fact that  a homeomorphism of the circle is homotopic to the identity on the circle?

Comment: @mathmansujo sorry that result was slightly incorrect. A homeomorphism is homotopic to either the identity, or a reflection in some axis. The result is easy enough to prove from a winding number argument - if you've ever proved that $\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$, then this corresponds to a homemorphism either inducing the identity map on the fundamental group, or the map $n\mapsto -n$ as these are the only two automorphisms of the integers.

Comment: actually I am reading the book by Massey, and the question is given without introducing the theorems used in the proof. There should be an easier explanation to this question without using big theorems. If you can find some explicit map or easier argument, then it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Which is the big theorem? The 'map extendable iff null-homotopic' result should be one of the first results you ever prove in algebraic topology.

Comment: @DanielRust: big theorem or no big theorem, using any results of algebraic topology to solve this problem is obviously an overkill, given the fact that you can easily write out the extension explicitly.

Comment: @Vladimir don't want to cause a flame but the OP tagged the question as Algebraic Topology, so it is right to use basic algebraic topology tools imho. Otherwise why choosing such tag?

Comment: @DanielRust No flame, no hard feelings; however what if OP tagged this as Fermat's Last Theorem and I somehow used that theorem to prove the claim? Would it not be ridiculous on my part, tag or no tag?

Comment: I'm a little confused. My understanding is that this is the sort of question that will  appear at the end of a chapter containing the 'big result' - in such cases it's almost always the author's intent for the student to use the result precisely to avoid having to write down complicated formulae which then need to have various properties proved about them, i.e. continuity. That's the strength of algebraic topology.

Comment: @DanielRust I am in fact confused too. The explicit formula is obvious for me at first sight, and it is not complicated at all. A really good problem illustrating the strength of algebraic topology would be one that has a simple statement but on the other hand does not have a solution that is so insistently obvious.

Comment: It's important to practice finding explicit solutions where possible, as well as finding abstract existence proofs using the tools at hand, for when explicit solutions aren't readily apparent. I think that's probably an amicable place to leave it :).

Comment: I agree. You are completely right;)